# The display fault on my MBP - anyone knows what might be the cause of this and how to fix this?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

A simple background of my MPB:

> macOS High Sierra Version 10.13.6 (15-inch, 2016 with TouchBar)
>   Processor 2.9GHz Intel Core i7 / Memory 16GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3 /
>   Graphics: Radeon Pro 460 4096 MB Intel HD Graphics 530 1536MB

Short story: suddenly my MacBook Pro is like this:

The internal display is totally bad, but the external screen is good:
[image]

A close up to the internal display - It's only showing a few areas on the top, and it's not refreshing (redrawing) after a few seconds after I unfold it.

[image]
Here is a complete story of this:

I was driving to another city (very far) the last Saturday, bringing this MBP with me and there is NO crash or bump on the mountain roads. The traffic is good and I don't have any panic stops. The outer side of MBP itself is always good. And I always kept it in a soft bag.

And I even opened and used the MBP last Saturday night. However, when I arrived at another midpoint last Sunday noon, I open the MBP and it becomes like that. There are about 10 hours between these two usages.

Another detail is that the place I drove about is a bit colder (around 10°C) than my home (around 30°C). And the place I drove about has a higher altitude (about 1,900M) than my home (nearly 0M).

Now I am back home and this problem still exists.

Some other information that I can provide:

- I didn't drive very fast.
- I used the MBP last Saturday night in a place of nearly altitude 1800M.
- I used the MBP [WITHOUT its internal display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/334839/external-display-external-keyboard-external-mouse-to-a-mbp-is-that-good-or-bad) a lot. Since I purchased this MBP, almost 95% of the time I connect it to an external display and do not even turn on the internal screen. (I connect the MBP to an external keyboard and mouse. I will put the MBP sleep after done my work and woke it up by pressing the external keyboard/mouse)

Does anyone have any idea of this?

Thanks,

Comment: Driving speed, temperature variations and altitude changes should not affect your display this way. This looks like a hardware problem not easily diagnosed without hands-on examination by an expert.